# given a set of lists/groups with a series of number, find matching numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

So given an n number of groups which have a series of digits ( no digit will repeat itself in a given group. How can i search for numbers that appear in alteast twice in 2 or more groups.

eg:

A: 1,2,3,4,5

B: 1,6,7,8,9

C:3.10,11,12

Answer would be : 1 and 3 as they appear atleast twice over the three groups

I have tried by comparing each element in group x with another in gorup Y and so on,however this isnt efficient and takes a long time to compute for larger data.

Comment: What data structures are you currently working with? A `List<List<Integer>>`? A `List<string>` where each string is a comma-separated list of values? Seeing what code you already have would be helpful.

Comment: do you have just a little bit code for us???

Comment: Are the lists always sorted?

Comment: @StephenTG no the lists arent sorted, i was thinking of applying merge sort

Comment: @DanW The [tag:java] tag should stay.

Comment: @Michelle List<string>

Comment: @JohnKugelman Why? Seems like it's just an algorithm that doesn't depend on a specific language.

Comment: @user2675364: Why do you have a list of strings for your numbers??

Comment: why don't you use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` to keep counts of each integer in your integer list array?

Answer (score 5):

One of the more efficient ways to determine if a set of items contains a duplicate element is to use a HashSet. Go through all the elements and add them to the HashSet, but just before adding an element check if the HashSet already contains that item. If the item already exists in the HashSet then that item already exists somewhere else and is a duplicate.

There is no need to ensure the data is sorted with this approach. Sorting any data is at best O(n lg n). The HashSet approach is just O(n).

To clarify the confusion in the comments, here is a psuedo-code version of the algorithm.

```
for Integer e in allLists {
    if (hashSet.contains(e)) {
        //e was added in a previous iteration of the loop and thus e is a duplicate
        results.add(e);
    } else {
        hashSet.add(e); 
    }
}
```

Comment: @anubhava If the number already exists in the set when you try to add it, that means that it exists twice within the data. Since it's been stated that no value appears twice in the same group, if a value appears twice, it's over two different groups.

Comment: @anubhava I have updated my answer with a psuedo code example of how duplicate detection works with the HashSet.

Comment: @anubhava Nowhere did OP ask for triplicates. If you look at the example in the question, he's looking for duplicates.

Comment: @Michelle: I think you both are correct, I got confused by these words: `alteast twice in 2 or more groups` +1 to this answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a global `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` to keep count of each number presented in arrays.

Since it is declared as, no list will contain duplicate elements, to find out numbers that are in two or more lists, simply iterate over the keyset of the map and check for their corresponding `counter`.

Complexity: `O(N)` where `N` is the total number of integers in list array.

Comment: +1 that would be a good solution meeting OP's main requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really give you any specific code as I don't know how your data is currently stored, but you may want to try these steps:

-Add all values from each list to one master list.

-Sort the master list.

-Iterate over this list, adding any values that appear more than once to your results list.

Edit: Since you're using a List, you'll need to split each string into a list of integers. You should be able to work out how to do this on your own (at least give it a try).

Comment: This might not work if the original lists contain duplicates. Not sure if they would, though

Comment: @StephenTG It's stated in the question that no value appears twice in any given list.

Comment: Well, I'm clearly blind, then. This method seems good, in that case

Answer (score 0):

If the data is sorted, as you have shown above, then you could optimize it quite a bit. Instead of comparing every element of every list with eachother, compare an element from A with the elements in B, until the value of the element in B is greater than the value in A. This only works if your data is sorted, as in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how these are stored (in an array or linked list for example) or if the data will always be in sorted order as presented here, so the approach would be different depending on that.

Assuming that you have an array of sorted values, I would go through each element in list A and do a binary search in lists B and C. Then I would go through all of the elements in list B and do a binary search in list C. If the data is unsorted, you should sort it first using a sorting algorithm (though I think the Arrays class has a built in sorting method that you can use)